# Can volume snapshots be used as replacement for Clonezilla images?

Tags: lvm

I've been always using classic disk partitioning and Clonezilla images of selected partitions for fast recovery in case of a catastrophic disk failure. I'm now testing LVM on a new system. It also uses whole disk encryption so the whole volume group is encrypted.

**Q1: Can volume snapshots be used for the recovery in the way I've been using Clonezilla?**

**Q2: If Q1 is yes, does it still apply if the physical partition is encrypted?**